# pyspark: dataframe from rdd containing list of lists

Tags: list, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I am new to Spark (with Python) and couldn't figure this out even after looking through relevant posts.

I have a RDD. Each record of the RDD is a list of lists as below

```
[[1073914607, 0, -1],[1073914607, 2, 7.88],[1073914607, 0, -1],[1073914607, 4, 40.0]]
[[1074079003, 0, -1],[1074079003, 2, 2.87],[1074079003, 0, -1],[1074079003, 4, 35.2]]
```

I want to convert the RDD to a dataframe with 3 columns, basically stack all the element lists. The  dataframe should look like below.

```
account_id  product_id  price
1073914607    0         -1
1073914607    2         7.88
1073914607    0         -1
1073914607    4         40
1074079003    0         -1
1074079003    2         2.87
1074079003    0         -1
1074079003    4         35.2
```

I have tried `my_rdd.toDF()`, but it gives me two rows and four columns with each element list in a column. I also tried some solutions suggested in other posts which might be relevant. Since I am pretty new to spark, I got various errors that I could figure out. Please help. Thanks.

**Added on 07/28/2021**. In the end I did the following to loop through each element and generate a long list and convert it into a dataframe. Probably it is not the most efficient way but it solved my issue.

```
    result_lst=[]
    
    for x in my_rdd.toLocalIterator():
        for y in x:
            result_lst.append(y)
    
    result_df=spark.createDataFrame(result_lst, ['account_id','product_id','price'])
```

Comment: Please don't post images. It's difficult for people to copy and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later used another way below to solve the problem without bringing the rdd to Localiterator() and looping through it. I guess this new way is more efficient.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql import Row
df_exploded=my_rdd.map(lambda x : Row(x)).toDF().withColumn('_1', explode('_1'))
result_df=df_exploded.select([df_exploded._1[i] for i in range(3)]).toDF('account_id','product_id','price')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = ([[1,2],[1,4]],[[2,5],[2,6]])
>>> df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['c1','c2'])

>>> df.show()
+------+------+
|    c1|    c2|
+------+------+
|[1, 2]|[1, 4]|
|[2, 5]|[2, 6]|
+------+------+

>>> df1 = df.select(df.c1.alias('c3')).union(df.select(df.c2).alias('c3'))
>>> df1.show()
+------+
|    c3|
+------+
|[1, 2]|
|[2, 5]|
|[1, 4]|
|[2, 6]|
+------+

>>> df1.select(df1.c3,df1.c3[0],df1.c3[1]).show()
+------+-----+-----+
|    c3|c3[0]|c3[1]|
+------+-----+-----+
|[1, 2]|    1|    2|
|[2, 5]|    2|    5|
|[1, 4]|    1|    4|
|[2, 6]|    2|    6|
+------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks Bala. But I want the results with 1st row as [1, 2] and 3rd row as [2, 5] instead of [1, 1] and [2, 2] respectively. In addition, the count of element list in the big list is dynamic meaning I don't know if i only have 'c1' and 'c2'. It could have 'c1' to 'c90' for example. In addition, in the element list there will be three values, not sure it will be hurdle.

Comment: @sguo: Answer updated.  This should give some direction

Comment: Thanks @Bala. In the end, I did the following to loop through each element and generate a long list and coverte it into a dataframe. 

result_lst=[]
for x in my_rdd.toLocalIterator():
    for y in x:
        result_lst.append(y)

result_df=spark.createDataFrame(result_lst, ['account_id','tip_id'])